# iPad and iPhone show one delivered iMessage but not on the other. Is message delivered?

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages

Sent message from iPad or iPhone and message does not say delivered. But when I look at other device it shows delivered. Is message delivered? Example message sent from iPhone no delivered status. Look at same message on IPad and shows delivered status.

Comment: Do you have the option turned on on your iPhone to receive read a read receipt? I don't know how the function is called but you can find it in Settings > Messages

Comment: Yes this is set on for both my iPad and iPhone. Just not sure why one says delivered and the other one doesn't. I have tried it both ways. Send from iPhone & shows delivered on iPad but not iPhone. Then send from iPad & shows delivered on iPhone but not iPad.

Comment: Giving it time or not does not allow this faulty behavior. Could you please address this to apple as a bug? https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this when the sending device was the iPhone, and I knew the recipient was on holiday and not online - the iPhone did not show delivered, but the iPad did. Eventually, when the recipient came back online days later, the iMessage showed delivered on the iPhone too.

This is a likely an iMessage bug/anomaly (which I wish Apple would address!) I would take the true delivery notification to be the device from where the message was originally sent.

Comment: Please report this as a bug to apple https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Give it sometime. Your iMessage delivered. It usually has to do w iCloud synchronization.